# i want to rewrite my url from htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to map this url http://123chatgroups.info/testclient/123flashchat.swf?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527 with simply  http://123chatgroups.info/testclient. The parameters here are default and wont change.

On the browser i will write this http://123chatgroups.info/testclient

and i want this http://123chatgroups.info/testclient/123flashchat.swf?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527 to run on backend with these static parameters.

I have to do this with htaccess.

HELP would be really appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(testclient)/?$ /$1/123flashchat.swf?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527 [L,QSA,NC,NE]
```

Comment: This works but i want my url not to show parameters. Currently its http://123chatgroups.info/testclient/?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527
i want it in the front to be like  http://123chatgroups.info/testclient

Comment: What is the URL you're entering in the browser?

Comment: 123chatgroups.info/testclient and when i run it it changes to http://123chatgroups.info/testclient/?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527

Comment: That's weird for 2 reasons. 1: My rule is not changing URL since I'm not using `R` (redirect) flag. 2: My rule is forwarding the URL to `/testclient/123flashchat.swf?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527` but you're reporting that you're getting `/testclient/?init_host=208.98.56.230&init_port=55527` **without 123flashchat.swf**

Comment: Yes thanks a heap its working. it might be my cashe But the swf file is unable to get the parameters now :(

Comment: Please help me i know you are an expert. Help would be really appreciated

Comment: Sorry had to step away for few mins. Can you pls tell me if you're still getting the problem, if yes then pls brief the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34397/discussion-between-awais-and-anubhava)

Comment: See if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179016/mod-rewriting-a-query-string-onto-a-swf-file

Comment: action script is a part of swf i think but i cant change or edit my swf file.... still stuck