# Why doesnt this htaccess rewrite work?

Tags: .htaccess, flash

Okay so I am trying to make it so that if people go to `/?char=USERNAME` it would show the contents of `/game/CharWidget.swf?login=USERNAME`. This is my code so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} char=(.*)
RewriteRule ^index.php?char=(.*) /game/CharWidget.swf?login=%1
```

This makes the url server side as `/game/CharWidget.swf` but doesn't carry the ?char=username and make it ?login=username so it wont show what I want it to show.

Edit; If it's easier doing `/char/USERNAME` to `/game/CharWidget.swf?login=USERNAME` i wouldnt mind doing that if someone could give me the code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string is not visible to `RewriteRule`s, so `^index.php?char=(.*)` will never match. (Except that, since you haven't escaped `.` or `?`, it *will* match e.g. `indexZphchar=foo`, which is probably not what you want.)

Also, if the user visits `/?char=USERNAME`, what the `RewriteRule` would normally see is just `/`; no `index.php`.  Finally, if this is in an .htaccess file, you'll generally also need a `RewriteBase` directive.

Putting all those fixes together, something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^char=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ /game/CharWidget.swf?login=%1 [NS]
```

(The regexp `^/?(index\.php)?$` will match either an empty path or `index.php`, with or without a leading slash.  That makes it a bit more complex than absolutely necessary, but also more robust.  In particular, the `/?` lets it also work outside .htaccess files, where the leading slash will be present.)

Ps. The regexp `^char=(.*)$` will also allow URLs like `/?char=foo&bar=baz` to be rewritten to `/game/CharWidget.swf?login=foo&bar=baz`.  If you don't want to allow such rewrites, replace it with e.g. `^char=([^&;]*)$`.

---

**Edit:** Unfortunately, [this isn't going to work for .swf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179016/mod-rewriting-a-query-string-onto-a-swf-file), because those execute on the client, and so won't see any changes to the query string made by server-side rewrites.

What you *could* do is make the rewrite external by replacing the `[NS]` flag with `[NS,L,R=302]`.  However, this will also change the URL shown in the browser address bar, which may not be what you want.  If so, another option would be to make the original request serve an HTML page on which you *embed* the .swf file.

Comment: I've tested this and it didnt work. It basically does the same as the code im using so it does the url fine but not the query

Comment: @user3096760: That's funny, because [I just tested it too](http://vyznev.net/?char=foobar), and it works for me. How do you tell that it "doesn't do the query"?

Comment: Well it comes up with something else if the query works and it doesnt do it

Comment: @user3096760: Ah, it's because .swf files run on the client, and so don't see server-side rewrites. See edit above.

Comment: Thanks, il use html instead of htaccess :)